# fxml файл не видит метод

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Собственно, вот fxml файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="420.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <FlowPane prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="420.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showDialog" prefWidth="100.0" text="Добавить">
               <FlowPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
               </FlowPane.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="100.0" text="Изменить">
               <FlowPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
               </FlowPane.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="100.0" text="Удалить">
               <FlowPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" top="20.0" />
               </FlowPane.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </FlowPane>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="60.0">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="18.0" promptText="Введите имя" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="140.0" />
            <Button layoutX="306.0" layoutY="18.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="100.0" text="Поиск" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" />
         </children>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets />
         </VBox.margin>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="420.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <TableView layoutX="14.0" prefWidth="420.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="ФИО" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Телефон" />
              </columns>
               <columnResizePolicy>
                  <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
               </columnResizePolicy>
            </TableView>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="60.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Количество контактов:" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Не видит showDialog (17 строка), хотя он реализован

```
public void showDialog(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        try {
            Stage modalStage = new Stage();
            Parent secRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("secStage.fxml"));
            modalStage.setTitle("Добавление контакта");
            Scene secScene = new Scene(secRoot, 380, 110);
            modalStage.setScene(secScene);
            modalStage.setResizable(false);
            modalStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            modalStage.initOwner(((Node)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
            modalStage.show();
        } catch(IOException e) {System.out.println(e.getCause());}
    }
```

Comment: Именно не видит? Т.е. происходит исключение или просто ничего не происходит?

Comment: showDialog подсвечен красным и IntelliJ IDEA предлагает создать контроллер. Пишет или нету контроллера или неверный скрипт. Но что неверного?

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы может быть 2.

1. Контроллер лежит не по пути `sample.Controller`
2. Вы импортировали `java.awt.ActionEvent` вместо `javafx.event.ActionEvent`

Соответственные решения

1. Переместить контроллер в `sample.Controller` или же поменять в `fxml` файле путь до контроллера.
2. Использовать правльные импорты